# Collect public blogs as pdf

Tags: pdf, blogs

Do you know any online tool  to collect the public blogs as a pdf ? Here I got printfriendly.com which gives only one page posts.I want all archieves from that url.
 could you please suggest me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not mention that you want free or paid service. But here's the one site that allows what you want. And it also support famous blogging platforms like Blogger, Wordpress & TypePad.

[**Blog2Print**](http://blog2print.sharedbook.com/blogworld/printmyblog/index.html)

Though it's a paid service, it generates a PDF preview copy of the selected blog entries that opens up inside the web browser - you just have to save this PDF file from the browser's cache to your hard drive.

Another online service [**BookSmith**](http://blog2book.pothi.com/app) supports only Blogger & Wordpress. It is nice & free. But it needs your blog's feed should be enabled or you have to give them your authentication info to access your posts. You can also choose numbers of posts to be converted in pdf.

Comment: Just This helps to my own blog..but i am supposed for public blog articles

Comment: @Navaneethan Then you should use BookSmith. But remember your public blog should have feed enabled.

Comment: But really it (BookSmith) is cool for bolgger and wordpress thanks for this

Comment: could you please suggest me for www.sarathlakshman.com

Comment: @Navaneethan Can I know which blog you are trying to save??

Comment: @Navaneethan It's a wordpress blog. But by feed you cannot get all posts. In such case you have to tell it's author to visit BookSmith, authenticate there & give the result to you/readers. It's good for blog's reputation too.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the one which I am using for my blog which allow visitors to save the post in PDF.

http://joliprint.com/

Here is a link of one of my post which will allow you to save the post in PDF format.

http://api.joliprint.com/api/rest/url/print/s/midnightprogrammer?url=http://midnightprogrammer.net/post/Integrate-DISQUS-For-Comment-Management-In-MVC.aspx

And moreover it's a free service!!

Comment: Sorry it doesn't work even i give it (http://www.sarathlakshman.com/category/my-experiments/)

Comment: It's working perfectly...what is the error that you received?

Comment: If you are having trouble in using the API then read about API here: http://joliprint.com/api/

Comment: Sorry, Joliprint cannot print this URL []  For the previous mentioned url

Comment: Well, it seems then joliprint won't work with the re-written URLs!!